# Subtracting and getting seconds as input in C

Tags: c, windows, time, clock

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    clock_t timerS;
    int i=1, targetTime=2;
    scanf("%d", &targetTime);
    while(i!=0){
        timerS = clock();
        while ((double)((clock() - timerS) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) < targetTime){
            //do something
        }
        //do another thing but delayed by the given time
        if(targetTime>=0.5)
            targetTime-=0.02;
        else i=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And what I want to do is having a loop which does something for (initially) an inputted amount of seconds and also doing another thing after targetTime-seconds have passed.

But after the first loop, to change the speed with which these operations are made(***more specifically -0.02 seconds in this case***).

An example would be getting multiple user inputs from user for 2 seconds, and displaying all the inputs made in these 2 seconds afterwards.

**First problem** is

If the initial given time is smaller than 1 second (for example 0.6), the other thing isn't delayed by 0.6 seconds, but is done immediately.

**Second problem** is

Actually similar to the first, if I subtract 0.02 seconds (in this case) from `targetTime`, it again does the other thing immediately and not in `targetTime-0.02` seconds as I intend it to.

I'm new to this "clock" and "time" topic in `C` so I guess I'm doing something wrong regarding how these operations should be done. Also, please don't give an overly-complicated explanation/solution because of the above-mentioned reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly initiated *targetTime* as **int** instead of **double**. Changing it to double solves the issue easily. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `clock(2)` system call, as it is obsolete and has been fully superseeded by machine independent replacements.

You can use, if your system supports it, `clock_gettime(2)`, that will give you up to nanosecond precission (depending on the platform, but at least in linux on Intel architectures it is almost warranted) or, if you cannot use it, at least you'll have `gettimeofday(2)`, which is derived from BSD systems, and provides you with a clock with microsecond resolution.

If you want to stop your program for some delay, you have also `sleep(2)` (second based) `usleep(2)` (microsecond based) or even `nsleep(2)` (nanosecond based)

Anyway, any of these calls has a **tick** that is not based on the system heartbeat, and the resolution is uniform and not system dependant.

Comment: I do know about Sleep() (I'm using Windows) and the likes, but the main issue is that I cannot make the program do the //other thing progressively faster. Consider a Zuma-like game where the user is allowed multiple inputs, but after every 2 seconds a new ball must appear on-screen. I want to make these 2 seconds smaller and smaller every loop so that the a ball appear after 1.98 seconds, then after 1.96 seconds and so on.

Comment: but `clock()` is not a windows call... I'm afraid you got it because the windows api emulates the clock call.... but it was first implemented in unix.  Why don't then use the windows api time functions?  I'm sure there's a complete set of system calls to manage time in windows (and then, windows has not seen interest until recently in havind a clock resolution under 10ms, I'm afraid) See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/time-functions)  for the Windows native calls for time management.  Again, don't use `clock()` (more in windows)

Comment: Said that I'm using Windows as a reference, didn't mean anything by it.

Comment: well, then, if you want your code to be portable (not windows tied to), then you have better to use the unix like system calls (mainly `gettimeofday` is the most commonly spread) and don't use `clock()`, which is an AT&T unix dependant system call, that requires HZ (a constant handling the number of ticks per second) to be defined.